# how to display a variable value along with the text in .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a requirement of printing the value is the popup,
I have used the below code

"code"

```
$('#warning').html('<p style="font-size: 12px;padding-top: 13px;">The updated list value is <p>' + var11);
```

[image]

but i wanted the value 500 to be displayed next to the text in the same line

can some one help me out with this

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to concenenate with `+` inside the `<p>` tag.

```js
var var11 = 500
$('#warning').html('<p style="font-size: 12px;padding-top: 13px;">The updated list value is ' + var11+'<p>' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="warning"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Just add the variable to the text of  `<p>` tag also you can use [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
$('#warning').html(`<p style="font-size: 12px;padding-top: 13px;">The updated list value is ${var11} <p>` );
```

Answer (score 3):

Get your variable inside the p tag :

```
$('#warning').html('<p style="font-size: 12px;padding-top: 13px;">The updated list value is' + var11 + ' <p>');
```